# How can I hide the image link in facebook wall with the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, facebook-wall

I have posted a message to my facebook wall through my web site, that contains also a picture. What I want now is hide the link of the picture that is shown there but still make the picture work as a link.
I am using:

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=> $message, 'description'=> $description, 'picture'=> $image, 'cb' => ''));
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to edit existing wall post?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you need is to use old REST API call `stream.publish` and pass an attachment. It has far more options and you can have separated links for image itslef and the one mentioned in post.

See: [`stream.publish`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish), [attachment format](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments), [how to call old REST API methods from new API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api)

Comment: I add in the array the 'name'=>$name, and now the link has been replaced with this name, so it is ok.